# How to match string between '', that's followed by "video_url:" text

Tags: python, regex

I have an html string with some Javascript code inside:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
...
var flashvars = {
video_id: '94577',
license_code: '38f7x%48',
video_url: 'http://www.domain.com/handy/url/f1d571a.mp4/?br=1114',
postfix: '.mp4',
video_url_text: '720p'
...
```

And I want to extract the string between single quotes that's followed by the text `video_url:`. I tried some regular expression but I'm unable to get a working one.

I think that is a good idea to treat the URL just as a string between two concrete characters, the single quotes ''. This way should be possible to avoid a lot of complexity.

Comment: What regex did you try?

Comment: See my comment in your answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
video_url: '(.*)'
```

used as such:

```
import re

messy_string = """/* <![CDATA[ */
...
var flashvars = {
video_id: '94577',
license_code: '38f7x%48',
video_url: 'http://www.domain.com/handy/url/f1d571a.mp4/?br=1114',
postfix: '.mp4',
video_url_text: '720p'
..."""

string_parser = re.compile('video_url: \'(.*)\'')
parsed_text = string_parser.search(messy_string)
print parsed_text.group(1)
```

output: `http://www.domain.com/handy/url/f1d571a.mp4/?br=1114`

a little more explanation: With regexes, you can specify certain groupings with parentheses.  So, I put parentheses around where the link would be, sans apostrophes, then called that grouping in the last line.  Here's a link to the regex, as well: https://regex101.com/r/lW6oA7/1

Comment: although to be terribly technical if you're just using the regex once, I guess you wouldn't need to compile it.. still, good habit.

Comment: It works, both in code and regex101.com but I did the same rule in regex101.com and I got a different result. Could you see if you can find any difference ? http://imgur.com/3YZObhL Kinda weird...

Comment: try adding a comma to the end of it.